# OpenSearch Java client - Find other documents like this one?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have a number of documents indexed in OpenSearch.  I've been told it is possible to have a "related documents" search, where I can find documents similar to one with an ID of *X*, but haven't been able to locate any examples or documentation for it.

Is it possible to take a document ID and then find *N* number of documents that are similar to it?  Any examples or documentation you can point me to using the Java client would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with a [`more_like_this` query](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/specialized/index/) and as it's not really explained in the OpenSearch documentation, you can refer to the Elasticsearch one on the [`more_like_this` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html).

It goes as shown below where you can search `my-index` for documents that are similar to another specific document with ID 1 from `my-other-index`:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [ "title", "description" ],
      "like": [
        {
          "_index": "my-other-index",
          "_id": "1"
        }
      ],
      "min_term_freq": 1,
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  }
}
```

`like` is an array where you can specify as many documents as you want and also free text.

Regarding doing this with the OpenSearch Java client, it should go something like this:

```
MoreLikeThisQuery moreLikeThisQuery = MoreLikeThisQuery.of(mlt ->
    mlt.fields("title", "description")
        .minTermFreq(1)
        .maxQueryTerms(12)           
        .like(List.of(Like.of(l -> 
               l.document(LikeDocument.of(ld -> 
                     ld.id("1").index("my-other-index")
               ))
        )))
);
```